# Is there a functional form of union using a set or array in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have an SET of id's in a WHERE statement that gives me valid seasonal days for certain taxa id's

```
WHERE
 ...
 tx_id IN ('00020','00030','00059') AND
 datepart('doy',dt) IN (
    SELECT TAXA_SEASON(1,'00020') UNION 
    SELECT TAXA_SEASON(1,'00030') UNION 
    SELECT TAXA_SEASON(1,'00059') )
```

and tax_sesion is a function for the 4 seasons I can select.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxa_season(SEAS INTEGER, EURING TEXT)
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER AS
$BODY$
...
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is there an functional form of union using a set or array in Postgresql

```
 datepart('doy',dt) IN (SELECT TAXA_SEASION(1,{'00020','00030','00059'}) )
```

Comment: How should the `IN` operator work in this case when on one side there is a set/resultset of sets and on the other an integer?

Comment: I've tried to use a pseudo syntax ..sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxa_season(SEAS INTEGER, EURINGS TEXT[])
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  E TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOREACH E IN ARRAY EURINGS LOOP
    RETURN QUERY SELECT TAXA_SEASON(SEAS, E);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;   
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Usage:

```
WHERE
 ...
 tx_id = ANY(ARRAY['00020','00030','00059']) AND
 datepart('doy',dt) IN (SELECT TAXA_SEASON(1,ARRAY['00020','00030','00059']) )
```

---

**Upd**: It was "lazy" solution does not required the changes in the existing code. The right solution is to invert the logic:

Create functions like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxa_season(SEAS INTEGER, EURING TEXT[])
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER AS
$BODY$
  -- Get ready to use (distinct) data for all values from EURING
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxa_season(SEAS INTEGER, EURING TEXT)
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER AS
$BODY$
  select taxa_season(SEAS, ARRAY[EURING])
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql; -- Note that it is simple SQL function
```

It would be more efficiency.

Comment: Thank you! With a  `SELECT DISTINCT TAXA_SEASON(1,ARRAY['00020','00030','00059']) ORDER BY TAXA_SEASON;` I get the expeted results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Abelisto finally it helps me out and the whole construct looks like this..

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxa_season(SEAS INTEGER, EURING TEXT)
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER AS
$BODY$
...find some date limits in the taxa tables 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- --------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxa_season(SEAS INTEGER, EURINGS TEXT[])
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  E TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOREACH E IN ARRAY EURINGS LOOP
    RETURN QUERY SELECT TAXA_SEASON(SEAS, E);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;   
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- ----------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sessions_taxa_season(
  YR INTEGER, 
  SEAS INTEGER, 
  LOC TEXT, 
  EURINGS TEXT[])
RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    R RECORD;
BEGIN
   IF SEAS > 0 AND SEAS < 4 THEN
    FOR R IN
      SELECT DISTINCT session 
      FROM sync_utm32 
      WHERE 
        date_part('doy', gps_dt) 
        IN (SELECT DISTINCT TAXA_SEASON(SEAS, EURINGS)) AND
        date_part('year', gps_dt) = YR AND
        session ~~ LOC
      ORDER BY SESSION
     LOOP
     RETURN NEXT R.SESSION;
     END LOOP;
   END IF;

   IF SEAS=4 THEN
    FOR R IN
       SELECT DISTINCT SESSION
       FROM sync_utm32 
       WHERE 
         date_part('doy', gps_dt) 
         IN (SELECT DISTINCT TAXA_SEASON(SEAS, EURINGS)) AND
         date_part('year', gps_dt) = YR-1 AND
         date_part('doy', gps_dt) >= 365/2 AND
         session ~~ LOC
       ORDER BY SESSION
    LOOP
     RETURN NEXT R.SESSION;
    END LOOP;

    FOR R IN
        SELECT DISTINCT SESSION
        FROM  sync_utm32 
        WHERE 
         date_part('doy', gps_dt) 
         IN (SELECT DISTINCT TAXA_SEASON(SEAS, EURINGS)) AND
         date_part('year', gps_dt) = YR AND
         date_part('doy', gps_dt) < 365/2 AND
         session ~~ LOC
    LOOP
      RETURN NEXT R.SESSION;
    END LOOP;

   END IF;
   RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result of request:

```
SELECT SESSIONS_TAXA_SEASON(2016, 4,'%XX',ARRAY['00020','00030','00059']);

 sessions_taxa_season 
----------------------
 2015-11-01-XX
 2015-12-07-XX
 2016-02-16-XX
 2016-01-21-XX
```

The rest is `sprintf` template driven from `perl DBI`.

Comment: `FOR R IN  SELECT ... RETURN NEXT;` can be relapsed  by `RETURN QUERY SELECT ...`